# norm of element in equivalent class in quotient space

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, quotient-spaces

If we have a quotient space $E\backslash L_0$ where $E$ is a linear normed space and $L_0$ it's subspace the norm of an element $L$ in $E\backslash L_0$ is defined as $$\lVert L\rVert = \inf_{x \in L}{\lVert x\rVert}$$ What I'm trying to understand better is why we can find an element $x\in L$ s.t. $\lVert x \rVert < \lVert L \rVert + \epsilon$. I understand that such element is not going to be an infimum, but how are we sure that this element is going to be in $L$? Does is have something to do with the fact that $L$ is a closed set?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is immediate from definition of infimum. If this is not true then $\|x\| \geq \|L\|+\epsilon$ for all $x \in L$ which means $\|L\|+\epsilon$ is  a lower bound; hence the greatest lower bound $\|L\|$ must be equal to or  exceed this, i.e. $\|L\| \geq \|L\|+\epsilon$ which is a contardiction.

Comment: I get that it's coming from the definition of an infimum. What confuses me is that we can always find an element $x \in L$ satisfying every $\epsilon > 0$. It's like there are no gaps between the elements in $L$.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if there is no such $x$. You will get a contradiction. That is what I have done in my answer.